# How to design an organizational chart/Hierarchy Diagram in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

How might I design an Organizational Chart in `Kivy`?

I need something like this image shows:
[image: Org chart]

Each item in the chart should be a button and if the chart is bigger than the screen, the screen should be scroll-able.

I tried using `TreeView` and `ScrollView`, but it's not turning out as I hoped.

Any suggestions?

Edit 1:

By using `TreeView` I end up with a structure that is to flat, to linear. It looks more like a vertical `BoxLayout` rather then the diagram I need.

As and example it ends up looking like:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your failed attempts to use TreeView and ScrollView? What was the problem? What didn't you like?

Comment: `@Shai` edited my original post.